# Icon questions != Wording questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

A lot of icon questions have been closed recently for some [good reasons](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions), i.e. that these questions mostly are too localized. There are also some [arguments against closing icon questions](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/whats-going-on-with-icon-questions) though.

We have also quite some wording questions on this site. Recent examples include

- [Would the users be able to understand "emp" as "employee" if I have space constraints?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/would-the-users-be-able-to-understand-emp-as-employee-if-i-have-space-constr) *and*
- [User friendly language for notifications?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23114/user-friendly-language-for-notifications)

I'm *not* judging the questions or the people behind those questions. But I was wondering if **most of the wording questions** fulfill the **same** criteria **than most of the icon questions**, i.e. being too localized and hence could be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking if we need a separate policy for wording questions I think we don't, not yet. It's not nearly as rampant a problem and I think think there's a risk in making it appear the copywriting is off topic.

If it's too localized, as in "no one else could ever find value in the answer to this question," **vote to close or flag the question as Too Localized**.

I don't think either of those are great questions, but one has been closed and the other downvoted. I'm on the fence as to whether to close the latter one; community flags/close votes/downvotes are often the tie breaker in situations like this.

If something isn't completely, clearly too localized/ect we'll often wait for some community feedback like that, which is why it's important to flag, closevote and downvote whenever appropriate. Don't worry about being "rude", you're just helping keep this site high quality and creating a better experience for our users.