# Why is meta.ux.stackexchange.com the only choice for migration?

Tags: discussion, support

## ***Background***

---

So you pull up a question and see that it obviously does not belong on **UX.SE**.

You try **flag** it by clicking **off-topic** and the last option you see is this:

> [image: This question belogns on another site in the Stack Exchange network]

So you click that and then you are stuck with this:

> [image: belongs on meta.ux.stackexchange.com]

## ***Question***

---

Why is **meta.ux.stackexchange.com** the only choice for migration?

For questions that are posted here at **UX.SE**, the two most common migrations I assume we will need are:

- **stackoverflow.com**
- **graphicdesign.stackexchange.com**

Why are they not available options for migrating a question to?

Comment: Maybe it's a moderator only ability? I'm sure other communities wouldn't want our junk questions because someone who didn't know what they were doing moved them all there.

Comment: Not according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work.  That's why there is a rep requirement, so that someone that is voting to move it _should_ know better than to migrate something that doesn't belong.  That said, my question is not who has the ability. My question is why don't we have a choice other than **meta.ux.stackexchange.com**.  The answer might be that you have to have a certain rep before the other options show.  That would fall in line with the link I just mentioned.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [More options for migration in close requests](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/more-options-for-migration-in-close-requests)? Basically the problem is Graphic Design is the obvious choice but it's in Beta (IIRC, it's graduating soonish though?) and SO is initially obvious, but most code questions we get here wouldn't really be good for SO (not elaborated on enough). I wouldn't want the SO migration option to be a "throw them to the wolves" button

Comment: @BenBrocka - You are definitely using the correct term when you say ***wolves*** with respect to SO, hahaha!  Regardless, we still need the ability to *vote* on whether or not a migration needs to take place, right?  We can't *not* do something for the fear of misuse, can we?  I mean, with respect to unlocking site abilities, that's what the reputation requirements are there for, to allow only those who are experienced enough with the site to use them, right?

Comment: Yeah, though experitise on one site doesn't necessarily equate to understanding which migration target is appropriate; for a few sites (serverfault and Programmers) being on the SO migration list was more of a curse than blessing because people migrated bad questions. Personally I think most experienced people here are in a decent position to judge if something should go to GD. I'm not sure migrating to SO (via the prefilled list) is ever a good idea though. Code questions asked here are verrry rarely up to their standards.

Comment: @BenBrocka - I've updated the question.  See what you think about that possibility.

Comment: What's the question now? If you update a question, please ***update the question!*** (You might leave a footnote if the update completely invalidates an answer, but that's not the case here)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The question is underneath the section titled ***Updated Question***.  If you are referring to updating the title to the question, I can do that.  Let me think on how to correctly word it.

Comment: What I meant was alter the question so that it is **only** the updated version. The "original version" is only relevant if there is an answer to it. If no-one's answered it, there's absolutely no reason to keep it at all (possibly only as a footnote, but even that seems pointless if it's not actually necessary).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I removed my _update_ and the _feature-request_ tag and will leave this question as a discussion. I posted my _update_ as a [new question](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/1570/40110) tagged as a _feature-request_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every site in the .SE network have Three "custom closing" reasons, where migration may very well fit. In our community we have decided that migration isn't the priority here. It was decided with the question [So, what exactly is off-topic for UX.StackExchange?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/so-what-exactly-is-off-topic-for-ux-stackexchange) posted in June last year.

The migration option is a strict moderator activity, which can be hard to find by some moderators at other sites. See [How (not why) do I migrate a question to another site as a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221480/how-not-why-do-i-migrate-a-question-to-another-site-as-a-moderator) for reference :-)

Being a mod at SharePoint.SE i finally got help to notice what could be migrated, and how to do it. The dialogue looks the same here (except from the site itself).

[image]

Questions younger than 60 days have the little search box which makes it possible to search for any other .SE site and select that one. But migration should be handled with care. And if in doubt, don't migrate.

So what do we do? Personally I post a close vote as off topic, either by the options predefined, or write my own custom close reason. After that I flag for moderator attention with the simple words "Migrate to GD.SE?". When a mod see the flag, he (there are only he-mods here) uses the dialogue above to post an imediate close and migration request (if it's a valid flag).

And for this extra work, you finally end up with a [Marshal](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges/72/marshal) badge :-)

Comment: I think it's safer all around if only Moderators can do the migrating. Some questions - and by extension the question askers - would just get crucified if their question got migrated to unsuitable sites (stackoverflow in particular). Mods have the ability to talk to other mods on those sites so if we're not sure we can just ask them to see if it's a good fit. Most of the time it isn't. Especially stackoverflow - either the question is too broad, or even if it is vaguely suitable the OP may have been question-banned over there anyway and is looking for backdoors to post instead!

Comment: @BennySkogberg - I'm liking the **Marshal** badge notion =D

Comment: @BennySkogberg - I used this question/answer as a springboard to request a feature that would automate the process that you currently go through.  Here is the [feature request](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/1570/40110).  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @JonW Yes, migration is a delicate topic, which needs to be handled with great care. Mods from different SE sites discussing a possible migration is a valid point, and I think we're good with mods execution based on flags they get. Let's keep it this way.