# Close reason "Implementation Question" may be taken too literal

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When deciding on close reasons, the community upvoted [Implementation Question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1393/4679) to the top. And as the answer was written then, I agree to it. Which css rule to use or which software to buy, is surely off topic. But OP also had doubts on the title, which is mentioned several times in the post.

I feel that over time the close reason "Implementation Question" have slipped to be interpreted to something that could be used in every implementation scenario, remotely. I dislike this shift toward an academic approach of User Experience where "the true meaning of" is more important and valid than "how can we overcome the problem of" questions.

To me User Experience is worth nothing if it's not implemented. In my work I implement User Experience as much as possible, and I take the knowledge from here into the real world. I thought this was the original idea behind UX.SE. I'm afraid where slipping away from that. Is it just me, or do you feel the same? What do you want UX to be?

Comment: I don't think I agree with you. We do welcome some implementation questions (such as what HTML to use for accessibility situations, tab orders etc). However when questions are asked where the UX decision has already been made and the OP is asking how to actually implement it, then it's not suited to this site as the UX part isn't being addressed, only the implementation side is. We're about *what* should be done. If the 'what' has already been decided then anything else falls outside the remit of the site really.

Comment: @JonW I appreciate your comment, and as you I think this question is important. My concern is that the “what” may have been decided to “don’t do X” but it leaves a gap of what else to do. I’m not talking about which technique to use but rather the design aspect of things. Delivering “don’t do X” to a developer will leave them hanging with a big question mark. UX has to tell “don’t do X, instead do Y” and possibly also “because of Z”. If not this leaves a gap between UX and Development, which is what I’m trying to bridge.

Comment: If not UX, who will fill the role taking UX amendments and translate it to developers so that they can implement it? Interaction Designers? Graphic Designers?

Comment: I agree with not just giving a 'don't do X' answer. That's not really much use. But for UX we should go with "Don't do X, do Y *because Z...*". But we can't really extend it to "don't do X, do Y because Z, *and this is how you implement it in JQuery*" because that's too broad a scope for the site. Stack Exchange itself may be able to provide info on each of the steps of the process, but no one site would, or should, be providing that.

Comment: @JonW Exactly! Let developer worry on technicalities. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, Benny.

For example, [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56621/designing-a-knowledge-base-search) question got a vote to close citing implementation.

It is a question asking how to help users navigate a knowledge base that is organized by a taxonomy.

Possible valid answers could include faceted-search patterns, miller columns, or some other approach.  This **is** ux to me.

The closest this question comes to the close reason is *using* the word `implementation` in the body of the question.

Comment: That question has only gathered one close vote though, it hasn't been closed or voted to be closed off by anyone else yet. That's why it takes 5 votes to get something closed; to stop them accidentally getting closed by people auto-reviewing. There will always be questions that are voted to close when they're not really appropriate to be closed off. And even if ones do get closed off they can still be reopened. That's one of the purposes of mods like myself - to be able to reverse such decisions if they've been made erroneously.