# Should the on-topic page be updated to reflect current policy?

Tags: support

After reading the [on-topic page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I posted [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/64831/47420), and was surprised to find that it was closed, on the grounds that this site is not about implementation techniques. After further digging and comment dialogues, it became clear that the authority being cited was [this discussion here on meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1391/47420), where people had voted against implemention questions.

Given that people like myself will, in good faith, read the on-topic page and base their judgements on what is there, ought this page not to be updated to reflect what seems to be de facto a policy decision of ux.se?